# What is the logic behind creating connections to a postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

For example, I have a backend server that connects to a database. I simulate sending a large number of requests, it makes about 40 connections, but judging by the monitoring, most of them are in idle mode.
Then I limit max_connections to one and the same number of requests are processed normally anyway. Just like our working database usually has 20-40 connections from the server and I don’t see any load dependence at the moment. Our server is supposed to make connections to postgres only once. Other connections - a consequence of some internal logic? Why are they needed if there is no direct connection with the amount of data?

Comment: Postgres has a client <--> server architecture so you need to make a connection to interact with it. That is just part of the process. As to the rest of your question there is not enough information provided to come to any conclusions about what you are seeing. Information needed: 1) Is there a connection pooler in the mix? 2) What is the code for the simulation test? 3) What is the monitoring actually doing?

Comment: Concurrency and transaction handling are a reason to have multiple connections for multiple concurrent processes. But it's up to the application and the proces that this app has to support.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  1) can't say right now. 2) heavy select in In a loop that runs every millisecond (request without transaction) 3)Just a lot of connections, but almost all of them are idle. Also a lot of transactions per minute.

Comment: @FrankHeikens 
That is, parallel transactions lead to the creation of a large number of cases? But I ran queries in a loop, sequentially. Okay, so the question is: why can the connection remain in the idle state after the request is made and the transaction is completed?

Comment: What form of idle as defined here [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). If it is just  a plain `idle` then the code is not closing connections when it is done with a query

Comment: Opening connections, using connections and closing connections, it's all up to the application that uses the database. Ask the programmer that wrote the application why it works the way it does.